# Delete rows based on multiple criteria based on two columns in a range or worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

My workbook has two sheets, Sheet 1 and Sheet 2.

Sheet 1 has a variable amount of rows and 19 columns (A - R). Sheet 2 has a variable amount of rows and 19 columns (A - R).

All values of the data I am working with contain letters & numbers.

In Sheet1 column A, I have the customer name & in Sheet2 column A, I also have the customer name.

In Sheet1 column D, I have the invoice number & in Sheet2 column D, I also have the invoice number.

Sheet 2 will only ever contain one customer name, however it can change.

I need to delete the full row in Sheet1 if the invoice number is not in Sheet2, but only delete the line if the customer name is the same as the customer name in sheet2.

The code below works however it deletes all lines where the invoice number is in sheet2 but not sheet 1, which is correct however it deletes every customers invoices not just the customer shown in column A sheet2.

Any ideas?

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Dim x As Long, Lastrow As Long

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")

Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

Lastrow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

For x = Lastrow To 6 Step -1

If IsError(Application.Match(ws1.Cells(x, 4), ws2.Columns(1), 0)) Then

    ws1.Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete

End If

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: *the customer name in sheet2.* Is that the same name in all rows of column A ? ie delete if  `ws1.Cells(x, 1) = ws2.Cells(2,1) And IsError()`. *deletes all lines where the invoice number is in sheet2* - do you mean is **not** in sheet2 ?

Comment: You can't have both be true: *"I need to delete the full row in Sheet1 if the invoice number is not in Sheet2"* meaning that there isn't any customer name to compare to (that row doesn't exist in sheet2) *"but only delete the line if the customer name is the same as the customer name in sheet2."*. Unless you meant that you want to delete the ones that *are* in Sheet2 but then you'll need to put the Match result in a variable, check if it's an error and use the index function for the customer name-check.

Comment: @Notus_Panda *Sheet 2 will only ever contain one customer name* so the name to compare can be determined from any row on sheet2

Answer (score 2):

### A VBA Lookup: (Non)Matches in Two Columns

[image]

**The Logic (Short)**

- If destination `D` is not found (`IsError`) in source `D`, then if destination `A` in the same row is found (`IsNumeric`) in source `A`, then delete the destination row.

**The Code**

```vb
Sub DeleteMatchingRows()
    
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet2"
    Const SRC_MATCH_FIRST_CELL As String = "D2"
    Const SRC_LOOKUP_COLUMN As String = "A"
    
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const DST_MATCH_FIRST_CELL As String = "D6"
    Const DST_LOOKUP_COLUMN As String = "A"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim smrg As Range, slrg As Range
    With sws.Range(SRC_MATCH_FIRST_CELL)
        Set smrg = sws _
            .Range(.Cells, sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp))
        Set slrg = smrg.EntireRow.Columns(SRC_LOOKUP_COLUMN)
    End With
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim dmrg As Range, dlrg As Range
    With dws.Range(DST_MATCH_FIRST_CELL)
        Set dmrg = dws _
            .Range(.Cells, dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp))
        Set dlrg = dmrg.EntireRow.Columns(DST_LOOKUP_COLUMN)
    End With
    
    Dim dmrIndices As Variant: dmrIndices = Application.Match(dmrg, smrg, 0)
    Dim dlrIndices As Variant: dlrIndices = Application.Match(dlrg, slrg, 0)
    
    Dim durg As Range, dr As Long
    
    For dr = 1 To UBound(dmrIndices, 1)
        If IsError(dmrIndices(dr, 1)) Then
            If IsNumeric(dlrIndices(dr, 1)) Then
                If durg Is Nothing Then
                    Set durg = dmrg.Cells(dr)
                Else
                    Set durg = Union(durg, dmrg.Cells(dr))
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next dr
    
    If durg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No matching rows found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    durg.EntireRow.Delete
    
    MsgBox "Matching rows deleted.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The OP says *Sheet 2 will only ever contain one customer name*

Comment: @CDP1802 It's obvious that OP said it but literally translated to another language, it could mean what I posted. Otherwise, it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Imagine Sheet2 is a list of unpaid invoices for one customer and you want to delete from Sheet1 only invoices for that customer.

Comment: @CDP1802 You are of course right but the code could work for a lot of scenarios by modifying just a few lines. Hopefully, OP will express his requirements in more detail. BTW, not entirely sure, but I think this code will work for the scenario you're describing. It's just a little over-complicated (my well-known tradmark).

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thanks for your efforts, so basically Sheet 2 is blank, I will paste in a list of outstanding invoices and select the customer from a dropdown, which then populates the customer name to each row in col A, if the invoices for that customer in sheet1 are no longer in the pasted data in sheet2, it should assume the invoices are now paid and delete the row from sheet1. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It should still work @GeorgeEastham, VBasic code checks if the invoice number is still on sheet 2 and checks if the customer name is in sheet 2. If the first is incorrect and the second correct, he puts it in a range (union) to delete all at once.